# Accessing download link from the loop with WP Download Manager Pro

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, loop, templates

I'm new to Wordpress, so apologies if this is a silly question.

I am using the [WP Download Manager Pro plugin](https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) to upload PDF's to `wpdmpro` post types. A user has to enter an email address in order to download.

In `loop.php` I loop through all `wpdmpro` post types and a specified category and tag

```
<?php
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'wpdmpro',
    'wpdmcategory' => $category->category_nicename,
    'tag' => $cat_tag
));
?>
```

Now, I want to loop through each post and access the download link attached to post, but I have no idea how to do this? The docs don't seem to outline this anywhere???

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        // ... how can i access the download link on the post here?
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried...

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php 
$post = get_post(); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

I am at a loss here!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You access the file direct link this way:

```
<?php echo (wpdm_get_package(get_the_ID()))['download_url']; ?>
```